# Make a bash script that read from a log file with deleting duplicate messages

Tags: linux, bash

Let me put like this: i have a server that every day creates new log file to a specific path e.g. /var/log/apache/file[date].log

I wanna create a bash script that reads this file (according to date) and then group its messages deleting the reoccurring msgs.

so i started like this:

```
grep "error" file_*.log # this * is the changing date each day
```

the problem is that this file contains errors that they reoccur everytime such as

> [datetime] PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in `file`

how can i do it in a way that repeated errors (although they have different times and/or IPs) wont be presented, but not for different paths.

## UDPATE

as an example lets have the following log file

```
[Tue May 14 16:05:33.942372 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [client 127.0.0.1:50427] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(PHPCLASS.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path/file.php on line 6\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PHPCLASS.php' (include_path='.:path/CLASS') in path/file.php on line 6\n', referer: anotherone.com/
[Tue May 14 16:05:50.176982 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [client 127.0.0.1:52448] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
[Tue May 14 16:05:53.890024 2019] [auth_basic:error] [client 127.0.0.1:52862] error: client used wrong authentication scheme: /
[Tue May 14 16:06:09.702323 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error]  [client 127.0.0.2:38880] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
[Tue May 14 16:06:11.563076 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [client 127.0.0.3:52994] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
[Tue May 14 16:07:10.237942 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error]  [client 127.0.0.2:38884] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
[Tue May 14 16:07:10.694641 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [client 127.0.0.3:53154] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
[Tue May 14 16:08:09.984855 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error]  [client 127.0.0.3:53318] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
[Tue May 14 16:08:10.610644 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error]  [client 127.0.0.2:38902] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
[Tue May 14 16:09:10.158302 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [client 127.0.0.2:38906] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
[Tue May 14 16:09:10.554661 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error]  [client 127.0.0.3:53478] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//exampletwo.com/file.php on line 230\n'
[Tue May 14 16:10:33.942372 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error]  [client 127.0.0.6:50422] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(PHPCLASS.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path/file.php on line 6\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PHPCLASS.php' (include_path='.:path/path/CLASS') in path/path/file.php on line 6\n', referer: anotherone.com/
```

i want the outcome to be something like

```
- Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(PHPCLASS.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path/file.php on line 6\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PHPCLASS.php' (include_path='.:path/CLASS') in path/file.php on line 6\n', referer: anotherone.com/
- Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
- error: client used wrong authentication scheme: /
- Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//exampletwo.com/file.php on line 230\n'
```

ignoring all repeated errors from different times/ips but not from different files

Comment: So you're saying you don't want to read those specific lines?

Comment: these lines will be there 10k times or even more, and i only want to read each line once without repetition.

Comment: then just exclude them in your grep query?

Comment: 1st error client used wrong auth
2nd error PHP notic
3rd error some random error

these errors will be from different times/ different IPs i dont want to exclude them, but i want to see each error only once.

Comment: something like mysql ```select * group by field```.

Comment: I am not 100% with you here, but it sounds like you are looking to sort see `sort --help`

Comment: if the datetime and order are not important could be removed by sed then use `sort -u`

Comment: sort | uniq might be helpful but at the same time it wont do what i exactly want. let me put another example in the question maybe it gets better

Comment: hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{delete seen} sub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){9}/,"") && !seen[$0]++' file_*.log
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(PHPCLASS.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path/file.php on line 6\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PHPCLASS.php' (include_path='.:path/CLASS') in path/file.php on line 6\n', referer: anotherone.com/
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//example.com/file.php on line 530\n'
client used wrong authentication scheme: /
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in path//exampletwo.com/file.php on line 230\n'
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(PHPCLASS.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path/file.php on line 6\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PHPCLASS.php' (include_path='.:path/path/CLASS') in path/path/file.php on line 6\n', referer: anotherone.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this for one file, you can do `awk -F '[][]' '!a[$7]++' input`.  To reset and get uniq messages for each file, you could do something like:

```
awk -F '[][]' 'FNR==1{delete a} !a[$7]++' file_*.log
```

Comment: this output was almost what i want although it was only 1 error from the file not all of them, can you explain why? maybe i can enhance it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the comment.  This prints each distinct error once for each file.

Comment: i have differenet errors such as PHP notice file not found, and auth failed and others but this only printing out 1 PHP notice about file not found.

Comment: But note that if any error message contains a square bracket, that bracket and everything after it will be truncated.

Comment: If you have `[` or `]` in the error messages it'd only treat them as unique up to the first `[` or `]` and ignore any text after that for the comparison. It's not that the output will be truncated, it's that the uniqueness comparison will be done with a truncated string. It'll also output the whole line rather than just the error message part of it.

Comment: btw `'f != FILENAME{delete a} !a[$7]++; {f=FILENAME}'` can be written as just `FNR==1{delete a} !a[$7]++'`

Comment: the other answer -accepted one- worked and now trying on to make this one work, would love if you can explain a bit the why $7 when i tried $8 it increased way too much but then $9 was closer to what i need but still with some duplicated.

Comment: It sounds like your error messages may contain square brackets.  Using square brackets in FS is not a particularly robust method!

Comment: some of them do contain square brackets, other not. i am not the one who is generating these logs so i can't control how they are being written.

Answer (score 0):

Use `uniq -f$N` to skip the first N space-delimited fields in the comparison. In your case, skipping the first 9 fields should work:

```
grep "error" file_*.log | sort | uniq -f9
```

You also want to not show the first 9 fields. I prefer [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56132800/1563960), but here is another good way:

```
grep "error" file_*.log | cut -d' ' -f10- | sort | uniq

# cut -d' ' -f10-` : keep 10th+ space-delimited fields
# sort : required before uniq
# uniq : drops duplicates
```

Comment: this will only sort them but it wont remove duplicates.

Comment: @YamenNassif no, this will not sort them, it will only remove duplicates from contiguous clusters of lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d' ' -f10- file | sort | uniq
```

will do the job.

- `-d' '` tells `cut` that the fields are space-delimited
- `-f10-` tells `cut` that we want the fields from number 10 onwards (counting from 1)
- The rest is straightforward.